# Catch error in batch sqlite command line import

Tags: macos, bash, error-handling, sqlite

I try to create and import data to a sqlite file through the terminal(OSX ML) with this command:

```
sqlite3 test.sqlite < /importsql.sql
```

This works fine, but how do I catch the error and stop the script when the importsql.sql has an error?

Right now the error will be printed as output, but I do not find a way of catching the error...

Is this possible?

Greetings,
matthew

Answer (score 3):

Catching the output is the first part:

```
sqlite3 test.sqlite < /importsql.sql 1>importsql.log 2>importsql.errors
```

Where `1>` redirects standard output and `2>` redirects anything that would normally have gone to standard error.

Stopping your script should be as easy as:

```
sqlite3 test.sqlite < /importsql.sql 1>importsql.log 2>importsql.errors || exit $?
```

Anything after `||` will only be executed if the call to `sqlite3` fails. `$?` is the exit code from `sqlite3`.

If you want to include more reporting in your script, you may find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15078816/78845) helpful.